# How to set an icon of module in odoo13?

Tags: python, module, icons, odoo

I have just uploaded a module in odoo marketplace. And it is showing me that.
[image]

But there is an **icon.png** in my static folder and in ***manifest*** file there is an image field also, with my specific image.

So please guide me how to set an icon for my module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add web icon attribute in your menuitem.

For Ex :-

```
<menuitem name="menu_name" id="unique_id" web_icon="module_name,path_of_icon" sequence="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Default location of Odoo module icon in the app index is:

```
static/description/icon.png
```

Comment: Exactly, as i mentioned in my question, there is an icon in my static folder means in static/description/icon.png

Comment: Select  "Repositories" in the left menu, and click on the "scan" option right next to the repo you want to re-scan.

Comment: Done, but same issue.